# Will Pulsar delete offloaded segments while deleting topics?

Tags: apache-pulsar

Pulsar supports https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/cookbooks-tiered-storage/, Tiered storage, which is great. I experiment this feature, and saw it put some files on to AWS S3, looks like 2 files per segment, both with the same UUID:

- `5780710b-393a-49cb-aff7-282901d7e311-ledger-9`
- `5780710b-393a-49cb-aff7-282901d7e311-ledger-9-index`

I think it would be a mess later if there are many topics, and I cannot figure out which file belongs to which topic by the name. If I delete the topic use `pulsar-admin`, the files stay on AWS S3.

Is there a way to manage this?

Comment: Yes, Pulsar will delete the offloaded files from S3 if they are no longer needed.

Comment: Yes, I tested, if it is beyond the retention time, it will be deleted, but if I use pulsar admin to delete a topic, they are not deleted.

Comment: Don't know if it is a bug or by intention.